# Insert the node slides in template

Tags: theming

Have not touched Drupal for 3 years already and try to remember how to do the templates.

Banner node -- I checked the field name: field_data_field_banner and wanted to print every node banner image up to 4.

```
According to dump: 
 ["field_banner"]=>
 array(1) {
["und"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(13) {
    ["fid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["uid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(37) "Golden_tabby_and_white_kitten_n01.jpg"
    ["uri"]=>
    string(46) "public://Golden_tabby_and_white_kitten_n01.jpg"
    ["filemime"]=>
    string(10) "image/jpeg"
    ["filesize"]=>
    string(5) "20388"
    ["status"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["timestamp"]=>
    string(10) "1426087127"
    ["rdf_mapping"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["alt"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["title"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["width"]=>
    string(3) "737"
    ["height"]=>
    string(3) "300"
  }
}
```

}

```
<ul>
  <?php if($node -> field_banner < 4){?>
  <li><?php print $node -> field_banner['und'][0]['uri'];?>
  </li>
  <?php }?>
<ul>
```

It gave error: 
    Notice: Undefined variable: node

Tried a few ways but I couldn't get the image appear in slide :(

Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: Are you doing it in $node--banner.tpl.php?
PS: don't use ['und'] but [LANGUAGE_NONE]

Comment: @PatrickRyan - banner in page.tpl.php.

Comment: @Namari - no it is in page.tpl.php so it can show slider on front page. i try [language_none] but still get same error

Comment: if it's front page why don't you use page--front.tpl.php ? have you try to put echo 'test'; to see if it works? It might be coming from the location of this file in the wrong theme, subtheme...

Comment: @Namari, tried page--front.tpl.php as suggested, but it is not showing that it appeared on page with dummy text. I tested "test" in page.tpl.php. it showed test. not sure if $node -> field_banner['LANGUAGE_NONE'][0]['uri'] is correct

Comment: install devel module and then dsm($node) in page.

Comment: You also need to tell drupal template with a theme suggestion in a preprocess function to be able to understand the overriding files: https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
    // If the content type's machine name is "my_machine_name" the file
    // name will be "page--my-machine-name.tpl.php".
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
  }
}

Comment: @namari - thanks for your help. I am still struggling. It is ok. I try other way.